# JSP acces to list elements in cycle

Tags: java, jsp

```
 <%
                            int a = 8;
                            int iter = 4;

                            for (int i =0; i <iter; i++){ %>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="con col-md-12"></div>

                                <%  for (int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) { %>
                                <%if (a>=0) {%>
                                <div class="col-md-3 marg">
                                    <h3><a href="//webdesign-master.ru" target="_blank">${products[a].description}  <input type="checkbox" class="cb" ></a></h3>

                                    <a href="//webdesign-master.ru" target="_blank"><img src= "/try/imgage/${products[a].id}" alt="alt"></a>


                                    <p>${products[a].price}</p>
                                </div>

                                <%}%>

                                <% a--; }%>
```

Why I can't acces to products list elements bu using a variable in brackets `products[a]`?(give an emty place in html page instead of picture and description) If i specify just number in brackets, (`products[3]`) all work correctly. [using a number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX2VE.png). **Products** - list which I pass from controller to html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You should really try JSTL `<c:foreach ...>`

Comment: I know about foreach, but html is complicated, and i can't use it, need to generate rows and columns 
depending on the number of objects in the database

Comment: That's exactly what JSTL has been made for;

Comment: and... can you explain please, how to use for each instead of my code? first cycle(with i iterator) generate 
the right amount of rows,  second (with j iterator ) generate a columns(for 1 to 3 ) with products. variable a is random now, for test and 
may contain different value

Answer (score 0):

You never specify what the variable `a` is. You declare the looping variable `j`, but you never use it.

Instead of (`<% for (int j = 0; j <3 ; j++) { %>`,

Try: `<% for (int a = 0; a < 3 ; a++) { %>`.

Comment: My blunder,  in my code I declare this variable, but not indicate in question